# TableLayout not receive background if i use HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-tablelayout, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying use TableLayout to make a table and is much informations to screen of smartphone, so i need of a Horizontal Scroll, but if i use HorizontalScrollView, the TableLayout and my button of the screen have the background blank, the background simply disappears. I try use ScrollView (vertical) in test and all work fine, so the problem is in HorizontalScrollView in my opinion.

I try to change the width to a number, for example, width:"450 dp" and all resolved, but to approximately "1400 dp" all returned... My table is very large, have approximately 21 columns, so they tableLayout is much higher of "1400 dp".

i'm losing the hope, trying anything and nothing resolved.

somebody help me.

image below:

TableLayout with all working, but with ScrollView vertical, cutting the table without horizontal scroll:
http://s11.postimg.org/k9hg1a79v/Screenshot_2015_02_19_15_43_56.png

TableLayout with HorizontalScrollView, all backgrounds missing, this is the problem, TableLayout, TableRow and button lost the background.
http://s4.postimg.org/iprnwxg65/2015_02_19_15_41_14.png

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_start_screen"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/table"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
                </TableLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_deny_state"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:onClick="fechaTela"
                    android:text="Fechar" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to inflate items to HorizontalScrollView one by one with using adapter. Firstly you have to learn adapter mecanism.

This is an adapter example for custom listView :

http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html

This can helps to solve your problem :

https://code.google.com/p/androidbeginner/source/browse/trunk/andriod/src/slieer/com/layout/TableAdapter.java?r=48